# convert gps lat long to x,y coordinates in arcgis javascript api?

Tags: gis, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

i am trying to build ambulance tracking application using arcgis maps.
i want to convert gps lat long to xy coordinates because my maps are accept xy coordinates.
i have tried with geometry service but it's to expensive task to ping server on each gps location receive.
Is there any other way to convert lat long to xy?
My base map spatial reference is 28600.

Comment: What is the question? Please update your post (don't reply to this comment) to state what is the problem that you are trying to solve. Including an actual question (i.e. a sentence ending in a question mark) might help getting an answer.

Comment: you did't not understand a question ?

Comment: There was no question and no question mark. Now you edited your post and  there is a question mark, but still no question. Your first sentence is a statement  that finishes in a question mark. Are you asking "Is it possible to convert GPS.....?" or "Willl the world start spinning in a different direction if I convert GPS ..?" "Is there anybody smart stupid enough to try and covert GPS ...?" "Where can I publish my library which can convert GPS ...?". Unlimited options, don't let your readers guess, make it explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only client-side coordinate conversion that is built in to the ArcGIS API for JavaScript is converting between longitude/latitude and Web Mercator (WKID 3857 or 102100). The [webMercatorUtils class](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.geometry.webmercatorutils-amd.html) does those conversions client-side. For every other spatial reference, including 28600, you have to use a [GeometryService](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html).

Answer (score 0):

[proj4js](http://proj4js.org/) will convert coordinate client side.

For example UTM 17 NAD83 to Lat / Long

```
var projSource = new Proj4js.Proj("EPSG:26917");
var projDest = new Proj4js.Proj("WGS84");
var pointSource = new Proj4js.Point("somenumber", "somenumber");
var pointDest = Proj4js.transform(projSource, projDest, pointSource);
```